# What is IB in IPhone

Tags: iphone

Any One Explain What is Interface Builder in IPhone???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a tutorial by [Switch on the Code](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-iphone-application-with-interface-builder):

> Interface Builder is good tool for
>   building complex user interfaces for
>   the Mac and iPhone platform. It is,
>   however, a non intuitive program when
>   you first start using it - at least it
>   was for me.

Answer (score 3):

Interface Builder is a "What You See Is What You Get" user interface editor. It installs with Apple's Developer Tools.

It allows programmers and people like graphic designers to develop UIs, without needing to write code (in many cases).

Interface Builder saves NIB files (.nib/.xib). When nib files are opened (when the app is run), the system libraries are able to dynamically load all the objects used to create the graphics elements in the original nib file.

Interface Builder is available for iOS apps, OS X apps, and has a history dating back to NeXT (so, it's been around for a while).

Answer (score 0):

inteface builder is a tool used to build UI(user interface) part in iphone programming

Answer (score 0):

It is used to make the graphical user interface of your application in a very short amount of time. it can get buggy sometimes and end up doing more harm than good.

Anything you can do in interface builder can be done in code, so if you are comfortable with laying out your UI in code go for it. Just keep in mind to organize your code well, having a lot of code makes your application harder to maintain.